# Updating nested JSON in array rethinkdb using Python

Tags: rethinkdb-python

I want to filter with userid and update to groupuserlist in user_url data using python.pls help me.this is my following code

### JSON

```
{
"channelname":  "TEST1" ,
"groupuserlist": [
{
"userid":  "fb422f9b-bcec-4a82-aa8e-5e0daf5b1a7a" ,
"user_url": {
"file_name":  "082754a9-0de7-400b-b951-56043367d234" ,
"status":  "success" ,
"type":  "image" ,
"web_url": "/uploads/fb422f9b-bcec-4a82-aa8e-5e0daf5b1a7a/082754a9-0de7-400b-b951-56043367d234"
} ,
"username":  "Zaw"
} ,
{
"userid":  "84a20d80-3ea6-425b-9185-8107e11f63bb" ,
"user_url": {
"status":  "success" ,
"web_url":  "/uploads/b818fc8c-971d-466f-b9ba-31045c7f6a41"
} ,
"username":  "kyawkyaw"
}
] ,
"id":  "992c993b-095f-4dd1-86ed-797065f8bdbb" 

}
```

### Python Code

```
yield r.table('channel').map(lambda doc: doc.branch(doc['groupuserlist'],doc['userid']==usr_id)).run(time_format="raw")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All I got the solution

`yield r.table('channel').has_fields('groupuserlist').update(lambda row: {"groupuserlist":row['groupuserlist'].map(lambda doc: r.branch(doc['id'].eq(usr_id),doc.merge({'user_url': weburl}),doc))}).run(time_format="raw")`